# Taking values from a table and echoing them out

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a messaging system for one of my sites and I'm having a lot of issues with getting the messages to show up.  For some reason I can't get the syntax right so that it will take every single value that matches the receiver_id will display if the user_id matches the receiver_id.  I had it working fine on my windows test machine, but when I uploaded it to my ubuntu server it broke.  So now I'm trying to fix the code.  What I have is this:

```
$m = "SELECT m.message_id, m.receiver_id, m.sender_id, m.subject, m.body, m.posted, u.id, u.username FROM messages m, users u WHERE u.id = {$_SESSION['id']}";

$b = mysqli_query($dbc, $m);


?>
<div class="mailbox">
<a href="inbox.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">Inbox</a><br />
<a href="sent.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>">Sent</a><br />
</div>
<div class="mailbox">    
<h2>Messages for <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h2>

<?php echo output_message($message); ?>

<div id="messages">
<?php
if (mysqli_num_rows($b) > 0) {
while ($mess_row = mysqli_fetch_array($b, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    $u = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id={$mess_row[1]}";
    $rec = mysqli_query($dbc, $u);

    $rec_row = mysqli_fetch_array($rec, MYSQLI_NUM);

    $s = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id={$mess_row[2]}";
    $send = mysqli_query($dbc, $r);

    $send_row = mysqli_fetch_array($send, MYSQLI_NUM);
    echo "<a href=\"received.php?id=$mess_row[0]&sender=$send_row[1]\">$mess_row[3]</a> Posted by: <b><a href=\"profile.php?id=$mess_row[2]\">$send_row[1]</a></b> on: $mess_row[5]<br /><hr />";
}
} else {
echo "No messages."; 
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  I thought I had it fixed but then it just spit out the same record five times.  I tried grouping which only gave me 1 record.  I tried moving the $s call outside the while loop but I'm not able to draw on the sender's user_id that way.  I just don't know what to do and I've searched all over for the past several hours and I can't find exactly what I'm looking for, or else I'm not typing the question right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you just use a JOIN to get all the information in one query instead of three?

Comment: You assign the query to `$s`, but you use `$r` in the call to `mysqli_query()`. Is that just a mistake in coping to SO, or is it in the original code?

Comment: I've made so many changes to the original code I copied the sent page and changed it so it was te inbox page.  I just missed that $r, it should be an $s.

Answer (score 1):

Use a JOIN to get everything in one query:

```
$m = "SELECT m.message_id, m.receiver_id, m.sender_id, m.subject, m.body, m.posted, s.username sender_name, r.username receiver_name
      FROM messages m
      JOIN users r ON r.id = m.receiver_id
      JOIN users s ON s.id = m.sender_id
      WHERE u.id = {$_SESSION['id']}";
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, that is much easier, but that extra bit of code was so I could get the username associated with the sender_id.  If you look at the echo in loop I use the sender?=(what should be username) so that the received page can populate the sender through the $_get without me having to call on the database again.

Comment: My code gets the username associated with the sender_id. It's in the `sender_name` column of the result. BTW, you should use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` so that you can use `$mess_row['subject']` instead of `$mess_row[3]`.

Comment: I can't get the mysqli_fetch_assoc() to work, I get this error: mysqli_fetch_assoc()
expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given

EDIT:  I think I might have fixed it.  I still had the MYSQL_NUM as one of the parameters.  I changed it so it was just $b and it seems to be working.  Thank you.

Comment: Why are you giving it 2 arguments?

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for hastily throwing this together. Hope it helps.

Use this as your query, then you won't have to go through and do that horrible extra set of queries to get the user info.

```
$id = $dbc->real_escape_string($_SESSION['id']);

$m = "SELECT m.message_id, m.receiver_id, m.sender_id, m.subject, m.body, m.posted, u.id, u.username 
FROM messages m
INNER JOIN users u ON m.receiver_id=u.id
WHERE u.id = '$id';";
```

Extra note: Your need to escape your session id string. I'd probably also verify it is just numbers using a regex.

edit: Use @Barmar answers query in place of mine. I'd still add the escaping/regex though.

Comment: @Barmar I replied to the wrong answer.  This entire thing works great it's showing up perfect, but I need to get the username of the sender and I don't know how to call that in the same call.  Somehow I need to associate the sender_id with the username associated with that id.  That was why I was using that extra line of code to call the users table and match it up with the sender_id.